# Bash - autocomplete <TAB> - find all occurence and auto select one

Tags: bash, zsh

I have checked a lot of other answers but did not really find what I am looking for. Problem is I need to reproduce this with a bash auto-completion a zsh function:

If I got this:

```
: ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Feb 12 21:17 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user 4096 Feb 13 14:11 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Feb 13 14:18 dotfiles
drwxr-xr-x 4 user user 4096 Feb 15 09:03 Downloads
```

In zsh I can type:

```
: fil <hit tab>
```

Zsh will complete dotfiles folder name by itself. or if I got more than one folder who contain the string, he will give me a selection choice with all the occurence.

Any idea or script that do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) or [fuzzy_bash_completion](https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion).

Comment: Ty :) will try that